# C# Mouse Move won't work in a game

Tags: c#, mouse

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer ShakerZwei = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer SechsSekunden = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        ShakerZwei.Interval = 6800;
        SechsSekunden.Interval = 6000;
        SechsSekunden.Tick += new EventHandler(MausBewegung);
        ShakerZwei.Tick += new EventHandler(MausBewegungZurück);
        SechsSekunden.Start();
        ShakerZwei.Start();
    }
    void MausBewegung(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 10, Cursor.Position.Y + 10);
    }
    void MausBewegungZurück(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 10, Cursor.Position.Y - 10);
    }
```

My Code works everywhere, but not in a game the camera doesn't, i already tried to change the "-10" or "+10", still doesnt work. Is there another way to move the cursor between 2 points ?